# Why does guild.cache.get() return undefined?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a weird problem. `const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('677199911430782978');` returns `undefined`. When I use this code:

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    console.log(`Client.guilds.cache had a value added.\nAdded value:\n${guild.id}\nCache size is now ${client.guilds.cache.size}`);
});
```

It returns:

```
Client.guilds.cache had a value added.
Added value:
677199911430782978
Cache size is now 4
```

All that data it logged is correct, and that is confusing. Please help!

Comment: Is the client already in the guild when you try to get the guild obect?

Comment: Yes, it was in the guild mentioned above.